# Ruby github API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, github-api

I am new to ruby programming. I was trying to write below ruby code to create a comment in Github gist.

```
uri = URI.parse("https://api.github.com/gists/xxxxxxxxxxx/comments")

http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = (uri.scheme == 'https')
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
request.body = {
          "body" => "Chef run failed "
        }.to_json
        response = http.request(request)
        response2 = JSON.parse(response.body)
puts response2
```

But I executed below script then I always get `{"message"=>"Not Found", "documentation_url"=>"https://developer.github.com/v3"}`

Don't know what I am doing wrong. Appreciate help.

Comment: did you try using a tool like postman to check the post request?
it might be that you simply using wrong authentication or should use encoded post request

Comment: Since you're using the GitHub API from Ruby, you might enjoy the ease of use that you can get from GitHub's official Ruby API client:  https://github.com/octokit/octokit.rb.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that you're authenticated first. From the Github API docs on [Authentication](https://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication):

> There are three ways to authenticate through GitHub API v3. Requests
>   that require authentication will return 404 Not Found, instead of 403
>   Forbidden, in some places. This is to prevent the accidental leakage
>   of private repositories to unauthorized users.

You can do this by creating an [OAuth2 token](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) and setting it as an HTTP header:

```
request['Authorization'] = 'token YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN'
```

You can also pass the OAuth2 token as a POST parameter:

```
uri.query = URI.encode_www_form(access_token: 'YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN')
# Encoding really isn't necessary though for this though, so this should suffice
uri.query = 'access_token=YOUR_OAUTH_TOKEN'
```